# x11vnc service failing with exit code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, x11, raspberry-pi4

Thanks!

I am trying to setup x11vnc service on raspberry pi 4B platform, but it's failing. Below are the status logs:

```
root@raspberrypi4-64:~# systemctl status x11vnc.service
x x11vnc.service - x11vnc service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-11-23 09:44:49 UTC; 10s ago
    Process: 1947 ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -display :0 -auth guess -passwdfile /home/root/.vnc/passwd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1947 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 23 09:44:49 raspberrypi4-64 systemd[1]: x11vnc.service: Failed with re...e'.
Nov 23 09:44:49 raspberrypi4-64 systemd[1]: x11vnc.service: Scheduled rest... 5.
Nov 23 09:44:49 raspberrypi4-64 systemd[1]: Stopped x11vnc service.
Nov 23 09:44:49 raspberrypi4-64 systemd[1]: x11vnc.service: Start request ...ly.
Nov 23 09:44:49 raspberrypi4-64 systemd[1]: x11vnc.service: Failed with re...e'.
Nov 23 09:44:49 raspberrypi4-64 systemd[1]: Failed to start x11vnc service.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Any suggestion on this will be really helpful.

I am expecting to enable x11vnc service on raspberry pi 4B.

Answer (score 0):

Try Restarting your OS (computer). Then try these commands :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable x11vnc.service
systemctl start x11vnc.service
systemctl status x11vnc.service
```